# R total average of a column updated for each day

Tags: r, dplyr

Here is my data frame.

```
structure(list(date = structure(c(18993, 18994, 18995, 18996, 
18997, 18998, 18999, 19000, 19001, 19002, 19003, 19004, 19005, 
19006), class = "Date"), sales = c(10, 40, 30, 20, 50, 20, 10, 
20, 10, 30, 60, 10, 10, 50)), class = c("tbl_ts", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -14L), key = structure(list(
    .rows = structure(list(1:14), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -1L)), index = structure("date", ordered = TRUE), index2 = "date", interval = structure(list(
    year = 0, quarter = 0, month = 0, week = 0, day = 1, hour = 0, 
    minute = 0, second = 0, millisecond = 0, microsecond = 0, 
    nanosecond = 0, unit = 0), .regular = TRUE, class = c("interval", 
"vctrs_rcrd", "vctrs_vctr")))
```

[image]

I'm looking for this output:

```
structure(list(date = structure(c(18993, 18994, 18995, 18996, 
18997, 18998, 18999, 19000, 19001, 19002, 19003, 19004, 19005, 
19006), class = "Date"), sales = c(10, 40, 30, 20, 50, 20, 10, 
20, 10, 30, 60, 10, 10, 50), average_total_sales_at_date = c(10, 
25, 26.66667, 25, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-14L), key = structure(list(.rows = structure(list(1:14), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -1L)), index = structure("date", ordered = TRUE), index2 = "date", interval = structure(list(
    year = 0, quarter = 0, month = 0, week = 0, day = 1, hour = 0, 
    minute = 0, second = 0, millisecond = 0, microsecond = 0, 
    nanosecond = 0, unit = 0), .regular = TRUE, class = c("interval", 
"vctrs_rcrd", "vctrs_vctr")), class = c("tbl_ts", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

[image]

I didn't fill the numbers all the way down, but hopefully this shows the idea. I'm trying to get the total average for sales at the current date, and each new date takes an additional one day of data in calculating the total average.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `cummean` in `dplyr`

```
data%>%mutate(cummulative_average_sales=cummean(sales))
# A tibble: 14 x 3
   date       sales cummulative_average_sales
   <date>     <dbl>                     <dbl>
 1 2022-01-01    10                      10  
 2 2022-01-02    40                      25  
 3 2022-01-03    30                      26.7
 4 2022-01-04    20                      25  
 5 2022-01-05    50                      30  
 6 2022-01-06    20                      28.3
 7 2022-01-07    10                      25.7
 8 2022-01-08    20                      25  
 9 2022-01-09    10                      23.3
10 2022-01-10    30                      24  
11 2022-01-11    60                      27.3
12 2022-01-12    10                      25.8
13 2022-01-13    10                      24.6
14 2022-01-14    50                      26.4
```

Comment: ah great that is a super efficient and easy solution!

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)
df$avg_tot_sales<-cummean(df$sales)
```

Comment: awesome, the same function I see but not in the pipe